# Is there a way to query remote repository information without creating a clone?

Tags: git, branch, git-remote

My specific need is to determine the default branch for a given remote repository, which I may not have a local clone for. If I understand correctly, Git doesn't really have a native concept of the "the default branch", though GitHub and GitLab do. In these cases, I believe that the current remote HEAD is sufficient.

More generally, is there a Git command I can use to dump information about a remote repository without creating a local clone?

(**With** a local clone, I can get a bunch of remote information via `git remote show origin`.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git ls-remote` to get a list of remote references. Typically "the default branch" corresponds to the remote HEAD, e.g:

```
$ git ls-remote https://github.com/cli/cli
91c4a5d828265823f6ed29129713778e2c839470        HEAD
[...]
91c4a5d828265823f6ed29129713778e2c839470        refs/heads/trunk
```

Comment: I think it's more than just "typically": this default-branch-recommendation stuff is in the base Git code. A hosting site would have to do extra work to get around that.